# how to get rid of text selection in wxwidget combobox component?

Tags: components, wxwidgets

In my program I want the user to be able to choose between some options so I was using wxChoice component. Unfortunately after user interaction (clicking a button) I have to show custom text (not from my predefined list). Everything works fine if I use wxCombobox control but the drawback of this approach is that each time user selects an element from a list, selected text is highlited. It is annoying. I want the component to be read-only like. How to achieve this ?

Some code to visualize my question:

```
wxComboBox* viewAngle = wxDynamicCast( owner->FindWindow 
    ( ID_CHOICE_3D_VIEWANGLE ), wxComboBox );
viewAngle->SetSelection( wxNOT_FOUND );
viewAngle->SetValue(_("Custom View"));
```

EDIT:

This control is used to set camera view in 3D object viewer application. Possible options are like: top, left, right, etc. It is also possible that the user moves 3D object using mouse. In that case I want my combobox to display "custom view" string. However "custom view" should not be a part of combobox list because selecting this option does nothing.
wxWidgets default implementation alwasy marks selected text. Which might be misleading for the user because he might think that he is expected to input any text.

Comment: Please explain some more.   "I have to show custom text (not from my predefined list)" - why not add the custom text to the wxChoice control? " user selects an element from a list, selected text is highlited. It is annoying." - why is it annoying?  It'd be strange if it was NOT highlighted after selection, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the custom text should be added to the wxComboBox control, the program could just ignore it when user selects that option.

Also, the wxComboBox's wxCB_READONLY style could be used to avoid the highlighting thing.